# CS50 plurality, printing winner

Tags: c, for-loop, struct, nested-loops, cs50

```
bool vote(string name)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(candidates[i].name, name) == 0) //W's
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
        else if (strcmp(candidates[i + 1].name, name) == 0)
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Print the winner (or winners) of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        if (candidates[0].votes > candidates[i].votes)
        {
            printf("%s", candidates[0].name); // 0 = bob/ first
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\n", candidates[1].name);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to print the winner of the election but I cant seem to wrap my head around this, any help would be very appreciated, PLEASE DO NOT GIVE ME THE ANSWER I need the perspective so I can figure it out please don't just hand it to me, with that said I'll still need the answer dumbed down a little

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and review your lessons on how loops work. It does not make sense to have an `if..else` inside a loop that returns both in the `if` and in the `else` part. The loop in `vote()` will run only once, for `i=0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few hints:

- in the `vote()` function, each candidate name should be tested until you find a match. The loop iterates on all candidates so it does not seem necessary to test more than one candidate at a time in the loop.
- in the `print_winner()` function, you should determine the best score then print all candidates with that score as there can be a tie. You can implement this with two separate loops.

To solve simple programming problems such as these, think of the steps you would take to solve the problem with pen and paper, decompose the steps into very basic tasks and translate these elementary steps into C code.

Comment: I did it chqlie I finally did it thanks so much I was getting so stressed out but taking that step back learning more about loops to refresh my memory helped more then i thought it would your a legend, couldn't be more grateful!!!!!!!!!!